# How to import "path.join" in module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I experiencing a problem below. All I know, it's because I added the `"type": "module"` in my **package.json** file. But do we have a way to convert the following code in module? I cannot find good resources so far.

> const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))( ReferenceError: require is not defined

---

My code:

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
```

Comment: There’s a way, but I would recommend you just use manual imports (`import Foo from './foo'; import Bar from './bar'; /* etc. */`) instead (which probably means importing `sequelize` instead of passing it in, unless you’re doing that for some good reason). They can be analyzed statically and are unsurprising.

Comment: What is `file`, i.e. where is the variable coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replicate this by using [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). Here's an example using your code:

```
import(path.join(__dirname, file))
    .then(mod => {
        const model = mod(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });
```

Note that this is run asynchronously. If you're using a most recent version of Node.js that supports top level awaits or this code is being run inside an async function, then you can use this code insteadd:

```
const mod = await import(path.join(__dirname, file));
const model = mod(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
db[model.name] = model;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function called `require` and you receive an error which tells you that it's undefined. This is a good indication that your `require` function is indeed undefined.

It is quite possible that you wanted to use RequireJS: https://requirejs.org/

You will need to make sure that RequireJS is already loaded and properly initialized by the time you try to call `require`.

If you are using NodeJS, you need to install RequireJS,like

```
npm install requirejs
```

If you are trying to use it in your browser, then you will need to link it via a `script` tag. Here's a tutorial for more information and practical examples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/requirejs/index.htm